# C++ (file handling)

Tags: c++

When we are creating a file using code, it is important to define the extention of file like .txt, .dat , .jpg etc. But in c++ if we ommit the
extention of the file it still work fine. Why is it so? Also explain how the system will decide the correct extention of file as every thing
is in form of 0 and 1 in the memory?

Comment: Files can have ... no extensions.

Comment: File extensions don't ever really matter. On Windows, you can set a default handler for file extensions, so that when you double click a file it is opened by the appropriate program; but they are not actually required.

Comment: C++ is code, so when "we are creating a file using code", that would include C++ too. Your question is unclear.

Comment: That's unrelated to C++, or any programming language. Fille extensions are just a convention, not required for anything. I think this answer from askubuntu sums it up pretty well. https://askubuntu.com/questions/803434/do-file-extensions-have-any-purpose-for-the-operating-system

Comment: Removing the phrases _"using code"_ and _"in c++"_ from this question does not change the question, but perhaps reveals that this question is not related to C++ or programming.

Answer (score 1):

The file extension is more like a suggestion. A ".jpg" file can have text in it and a ".txt" file can be sound. A file can have no extension. Even though it is relatively rare on windows, it is more common on systems like Linux.

We add extensions to tell the operating system and any software that will use the file what it contains. For example, when there is a ".mp3" file, the OS and other programs will know that it is a MPEG sound file.

You don't need extensions if you know what the file contains. However, since other people/programs might not know what the file contains, it is a good idea to use extensions.

Comment: File types can be "deduced" with magic number in "header".